# Будет ли это считаться dependency injection

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, dependency-injection, solid

Уже прочел ни одну статью по поводу dependency injection: и у всех этих статьях сказано, что dependency injection - одна из реализаций inversion of control, мы внедряем зависимости из вне, но во всех примерах нашел то, что внедренная зависимость является какой-либо абстракцией либо же реализацей:

```
public interface Music {}

class RockMusic implements Music {}

class PopMusic implements Music {}

class MusicPlayer{

private Music music;

public void setMusic(Music music) {
    this.music = music;
  }
}
```

Будет ли это считаться dependency injection, если заменить ссылку вместо интерфейса Music на RockMusic?

```
class RockMusic {}

class MusicPlayer{

private RockMusic rockMusic;

public void setMusic(RockMusic rockMusic) {
    this.rockMusic = rockMusic;
}
```

}

Понятное дело, что лучше использовать 5 принцип SOLID - dependency inversion, но давайте не будем брать это во внимание

Comment: Всё, что инжектится - будет dependecy injection))  Так что да, будет считаться, но в текущем примере смысла такого подхода иметь не будет конечно же

Answer (score 1):

Плохая идея указывать конкретный класс, а не интерфейс, то есть кроме как RockMusic вы больше ничего присвоить и не сможете

```
class MusicPlayer{

private RockMusic rockMusic;

public void setMusic(RockMusic rockMusic) {
    this.rockMusic = rockMusic;
}
}
```

Если сделать вот так

```
class MusicPlayer{

private Music music;

public void setMusic(Music music) {
    this.music = music;
  }
}
```

То можете присваивать другие реализации(RockMusic,PopMusic) интерфейса Music, не меняя сам класс и это будет Dependency Injection

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что dependency injection - это то что зависимости должны быть абстракцией  и инжектятся из вне? Может все-таки первое утверждение про абстракцию тут лишнее, ибо это же dependency inversion принцип?

Comment: @javaStacker Я нашёл пример с [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java), но там есть ссылка на источник. В том примере используется абстракция в виде интерфейсов, если вы нашли другие источники то присылайте, посмотрим, обсудим